# Convert htaccesss to ngix

Tags: .htaccess, nginx

In .htaccess file I have: Options MultiViews , how it rewrite to ngix ? now I'm getting error:

```
500 Internal Server Error

nginx/1.2.8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this htaccess to nginx converter

http://winginx.com/htaccess

Comment: No convert in my situation